# Datepicker appearing at the end of the page

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

For some reason, my datepicker is appearing at the bottom of the page not next to my textbox. The css (- can post if requested) wasn't changed from default and I tried messing around with Inspect element but I was not successful. Can anyone guide me as to where this bug is emerging from?

Textbox:

```
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfAppointment)</td>
            <th>Time</th><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeOfAppointment)</td>
        </tr>
```

End of page:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateOfAppointment").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });

        $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Almost certainly a css issue. The calendar is probably an absolutely positioned element - check the value of the `top` attribute

Comment: @stephenmuecke it's at 100% at the moment.

Comment: `top: 100%` or `top: 100px` ? (% seems odd). Just modify it in the browser tools (say `top: 20px;`) to see if there is any difference. If so I suspect there must be something else in your css which is overriding the datepickers css

Comment: 'top: 100%'. If I change the value the datepicker is moved, however, I want it 'attached' to the text box not within a 'fixed top' so to say.

Comment: Yes I know, but it should be set in the correct position by default which makes me think there must be something else in your css which is causing it to be re-positioned. All I can suggest is to use the browser tools and see if you can identify whats overriding it.

Comment: Could it be a confusion between boostrap.css and datepicker.css cause the .dropdown-menu is being used from datepicker.css and .datepicker from datepicker.css

Comment: The problem is not the css but the scripts I have referenced

Comment: As @rikket mentioned - you are missing dropdown from bootstrap. Include it and it will work fine. I just found it out.